# Avoid table td repetition in WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created my first WordPress Theme from HTML and I want to add a space to the right hand side of my blog posts with profile information and links to other sites etc..

I am using the below code and it seems to repeat the table td where I would like to add the profile and other information?

Can anyone shed some light on a solution for this?
To see [what it looks like](http://blog.melbournebridalguide.com.au/).

```
<table style="width: 1000px; height: 150px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 740px">    
            <table style="width: 740px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 200px; height: 44px" background='Date.jpg'>
                        <h2>
                        <?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?>
                    </h2>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 540px; height: 44px" background='Title.jpg'>
                    <h4>
                        " rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?>
                    </h4>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">

                    <div class="entry">
                    <?php the_content(); ?></div>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 44px" background='Comments.jpg'>
                    Posted By <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
                </td>
                <td style="height: 44px" background='Comments.jpg'>
                    in <p class="postmetadata"><?php _e( 'Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' );    ?></p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </td>
    <td style="width: 260px">
        SIDEBAR AND PROFILE TAGS HERE</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How I can fix this issue in the `index.php`?

Comment: 1998 called....

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so]. I've edited your post for clarity, please note that the code indentation can be done automatically in *any good code editor* and it makes wonders to understand the code logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing your table *inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop)*. That sidebar `<td style="width: 260px">` is being printed at every post. It is not a sidebar for all posts, it's just an individual sidebar to each post.

You'll need to read about [Theme Development at the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) to understand theme structures and best practices.

The reference to 1998 made in a comment is that tables are not used for layout purposes since long ago, see [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/83073/1287812).
I'd suggest that you search for *Starter Themes* (like [this](http://underscores.me/)) to build upon. For complete, exemplary, themes look for WordPress default ones, from [Twenty Ten](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyten) to [Twenty Fourteen](http://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfourteen), to see how themes evolved in the last years.